# Radio buttons doesn't get disabled once clicked

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" id="checkMain" />
<input type="radio" id="checkMain1" />
<input type="radio" id="checkMain2" />

$(function()
   {
    $("input[id=checkMain]").click(function () {
        var otherCks = $("input[id^=checkMain]").not(this);
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".child").attr("disabled", true);
            otherCks.removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(".child").removeAttr("disabled");
            otherCks.attr("disabled", true)
        }
    });
    $("#chk_all").click(function() {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        $("input[id^=chk]").each(function () {
            this.checked = checked_status;
        });
    });
});

$(function()
    {
     $("input[id=checkMain1]").click(function () {
         var otherCks = $("input[id^=checkMain]").not(this);
         if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
             $(".child,.child1").attr("disabled", true);
             otherCks.removeAttr("disabled");
         } else {
             $(".child,.child1").removeAttr("disabled");
              otherCks.attr("disabled", true)
         }
     });
     $("#chk_all").click(function() {
         var checked_status = this.checked;
         $("input[id^=chk]").each(function () {
             this.checked = checked_status;
         });
     });
 });


$(function()
     {
      $("input[id=checkMain2]").click(function () {
          var otherCks = $("input[id^=checkMain]").not(this);
          if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
              $(".child,.child1").attr("disabled", true);
              otherCks.removeAttr("disabled");
          } else {
              $(".child,.child1").removeAttr("disabled");
              otherCks.attr("disabled", true)
          }
      });
      $("#chk_all").click(function() {
          var checked_status = this.checked;
          $("input[id^=chk]").each(function () {
              this.checked = checked_status;
          });
      });
  });
```

Sample code in http://jsfiddle.net/harshilshah/sBgZw/23

The above code works perfectly for checkboxes but dosent work for radio buttons

In short,the working should be like this : when I click on radiobutton1 the others should get disabled(not available). When I reclick on radiobutton1 the others should be available again.

Comment: sample code in http://jsfiddle.net/harshilshah/sBgZw/23/

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which exact radio buttons would you want to be disabled when clicked?

Comment: the above code works perfectly for checkboxes but dosent work for radio buttons

Comment: in short,the working should be like this : when i click on radiobutton1 the others should get disabled(not available).when i reclick on radiobutton1 the others should be available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle and the code above don't match, but the fiddle itself works perfectly (for checkboxes).

For radios, this replacement also works.

```
<input type="radio" id="chkMain" name="chkMain"/>
<input type="radio" id="chkMain1" name="chkMain" />
<input type="radio" id="chkMain2" name="chkMain" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk1" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk2" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk3" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk4" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk5" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk6" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="radio" name="chkChild" id="chk7" disabled="true" />
```

Obviously however, once you disable the other radio buttons, there is no way to "unselect all" nor "select another" - not normally.

If you use this code to mark the radio button with a fake class, you can toggle the button (**use with the html code above**)

```
$("input[id^='chkMain']").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).attr("checked",false);
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
   $("input[id^='chkMain']").not(this).attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
    $(".child").attr("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

**EDIT**

Just look at

- http://jsfiddle.net/sBgZw/25/ (click again to enable all radios)
  or
- http://jsfiddle.net/sBgZw/26/ (click selected radio to "deselect all")

Comment: hey, ur code gives multiple options for selection .. when i click on radiobutton1 then on radiobutton2 the check option on radiobutton1 should be removed rite?? n the child are checkboxes not radiobuttons..

Comment: @Harshil: If you just want to restrict the user to one option from a set of option, you can use plain radio buttons. No need for JavaScript. At least this is what I understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to repeat the code for each element ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). Just do:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $("input[id^=checkMain]").click(function () {
           var otherCks = $("input[id^=checkMain]").not(this);
           if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
               $(this).attr("disabled", true);
               otherCks.removeAttr("disabled");
           } else {
               $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
               otherCks.attr("disabled", true)
           }
       });
   });
   ```
2. In your code you have `$(".child").attr("disabled", true);` but the elements don't have a class `child`. Just replace it with `this` which makes more sense anyway (see code above).
3. <del>Even then, you cannot change the `disabled` state anymore because disabled radio buttons don't receive the click event.</del> See update.
4. For what it's worth: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sBgZw/24/). But it only works for the first time due to the reason mentioned in 3.

**Update:**

I see now what you are aiming at. The problem is that clicking a radio button again does *not* deselect it. So only the `else` will be executed every time. A radio button gets deselected by clicking *an other radio button*. But if you disable the others, the is no way to deselect it. You could, keep track of the selected state otherwise an manually deselect it, but is it worth the effort?

Why are you doing this at all? Seems to be an unnecessary hurdle for the user.

Comment: just workin on my webpage... so a radio button gets deselected by clicking on other radiobuttons is it??

Comment: @Harshil: Yes. Why do you want to disable the other radio buttons at all? If a user wants to select another option he'd have to click the previous selected first and then the other. This is not very user friendly.

Comment: is there any other way as if the user clicks on radiobutton1, then the user clicks on radiobutton2 this automatically removes the check in radiobutton1,because im providing user only one option...

Comment: @Harshil: **Radio buttons are for selecting only one option!** That is their purpose. This is their functionality out-of-the-box. No need to add any behaviour. Checkboxes: Select multiple options from a set. Radio buttons: Select *one* option from a set. See: http://jsfiddle.net/veKFX/1/